# What's the difference between setGravity=right and setLayoutDirection=rtl in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

When I want to change the direction of layout to right if I assign `android:gravity="right"` I will give the same result as when I assign `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`.

I want to know the difference between two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtl` means `"right to left"`, you would use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` if you wanted a view group to display content specifically for right to left languages (always) like Arabic. This is why it is aligning your view to the right. That said, I would recommend that you shy away from ever using `layoutDirection` since it overrides whatever the locale of the device is.

`android:gravity="right"` will align a view to the right. I also recommend that you don't use this (or `gravity="left"`) because it will not adjust for `rtl` languages, so if you ever release an Arabic version of the app the layout will look odd for your Arabic users.

Instead you should use `android:gravity="end"` as this will align your view right in `ltr` languages (English) and left in `rtl` languages (Arabic). You need to have a `minSDK>17` to use end and start alignments, but I am assuming you are because you also need a min sdk of 17 to use `layoutDirection`.

Answer (score 0):

This is RTL(Right to left) Layout. Everything is aligned from right to left for those who know Urdu or Arabic.

[image: Simple RTL Layout]
[image: RTL layout for localization]

`layout_gravity = "right"` align your view to right of parent. Refer the image. Only TextView is aligned to right and everything else is left to right.

[image]